# IP cameras viewable in web Browser

Tags: ip-camera

I'm looking for IP camera (one indoor and one outdoor) where the video stream can be displayed in web browser (without additional plugin). I already bought the following:

- [Xiaomi Mi Home Security Camera 360°](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07KCZ1J2V/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1642&creative=6746&creativeASIN=B07KCZ1J2V&linkCode=as2&tag=lucidarme-21&linkId=7dde62e69eaa5d461193935d8efbf257)
- [Foscam C2](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B013GJ1QJU/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1642&creative=6746&creativeASIN=B013GJ1QJU&linkCode=as2&tag=lucidarme-21&linkId=98845c1249621d4c4892935159f8e843)

The first one only works with the Xiaomi Mi app, and the second one needs a plugin for working in web browsers.